# ajax like button django

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, django

my ajax jquery :

```
 $(".likebutton").on('click', function () {
  post_id=$(this).attr('name');
  console.log('CLICKED IN LIKE');
    $.ajax({

    dataType: 'json',

    url: post_id +'/like/',
    data: {


  },
  success: function (data) {
       alert("SUCESSS");
      if (data.success) {
       console.log("SUCCESS")
        $(this).parents('.timeline-footer').html('<p class="pull-left 
   m-r-15">'+data.likecount+ 'Likes </p>'+
                 '<a class="likebutton" style="color: blue"'+
                   'href="dashboard/tasks/'+ post_id +'/like/"'+ 
  'class="m-r-15 text-inverse-lighter"><i'+
                        'class="fa fa-thumbs-up fa-fw fa-lg m-r-3"> 
 </i>'+
                    'Like</a>'+
                '<a href="dashboard/tasks/'+post_id  +'/$/" class="m- 
 r-15 text-inverse-lighter"><i'+
                        'class="fa fa-comments fa-fw fa-lg m-r-3"> 
    </i>'+
                    'Comment</a>')

        // here you update the HTML to change the active to innactive
      }else{
      console.log("ERROR");
        alert("ajax call not success.");
      }
 }
});
 });
```

my like template  like_comment2.html:

```
<p class="pull-left m-r-15"> {{ obj.like.count }} Likes </p>

<form action="{% url 'student:like' pk=obj.id %}" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
 <input type="submit" value="Like" name="{{ obj.id }}" 
class="likebuttons m- 
r-15 text-inverse-lighter" {% if request.user in obj.like.all %} 
style="color: blue" {% endif %}"></input><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up fa- 
fw 
fa-lg m-r-3"></i>


</form>
```

My view:

```
def LikeToggleView(request,pk=None):
print("NOT AJAX")
if request.is_ajax():
    post_id = request.POST.get('post_id')
    response_data = {}
    obj = get_object_or_404(Task, pk=post_id)

    user = request.user

    print("AJAX LIKE")

    if user in obj.like.all():
             obj.like.remove(user)
             note = Notification.objects.create(sender=user, task=obj, 
 notification = user.username + ' Disliked Your Post ' + obj.title)
             note.receiver.add(obj.student)
    else:
             obj.like.add(user)
             note = Notification.objects.create(sender=user, task=obj, 
  notification = user.username + '  Liked Your Post ' + obj.title)
             note.receiver.add(obj.student)



    response_data['likecount'] = obj.like.count

    return JsonResponse(response_data)
```

I want to update the number of likes in the template using ajax.Seems like its not getting into the ajax call :It printing "Not AJax" in the terminal

my urls.py

```
url(r'^dashboard/tasks/(?P<pk>\d+)/like/$', views.LikeToggleView, 
name='like'),
```

The console is showing errors:
GET http://localhost:8000/student/dashboard/tasks/154/like/ 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:8000/student/dashboard/tasks/154/like/ 404 (Not Found)

14:21:37.896 :8000/student/dashboard/tasks/154/like/:1 POST http://localhost:8000/student/dashboard/tasks/154/like/ 500 (Internal Server Error) 
Also its firing the jquery onclick two times when i click on like button

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = 'student'

urlpatterns=[
url(r'^dashboard/tasks/$',views.StudentDashView,name='dashboard'),
url(r'^dashboard/tasks/ajax/reload/$', views.ajax_change_status, 
name='ajax_change_status'),

url(r'^dashboard/tasks/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.TaskDetailView, 
name='task-detail'),
url(r'^dashboard/tasks/(?P<pk>\d+)/like/$', views.LikeToggleView, 
name='like'),
url(r'^add-mentor/$',views.AddMentor,name='add_mentor'),
url(r'^trainer-profile/(?P<trainer_id>\d+)/$', 
views.TrainerPublicProfile, name='trainer_public_profile'),
url(r'^add-as-mentor/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.AddAsMentor, 
name='add_as_mentor'),
url(r'change-as-mentor/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.ChangeAsMentor, 
name='change_as_mentor'),
url(r'^accept-to-hub/(?P<pk>\d+)/(?P<notify>\d+)/$', views.AcceptHub, 
name='accept_hub'),
url(r'^reject-to-hub/(?P<pk>\d+)/(?P<notify>\d+)/$', views.RejectHub, 
name='reject_hub'),
url(r'^accept-mentor/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.AcceptMentor, 
name='accept_as_mentor'),
url(r'^reject-mentor/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.RejectMentor, 
name='reject_as_mentor'),
url(r'^promote-to-excom/(?P<user>\d+)/$', views.PromoteExcom, 
name='promote'),
url(r'^depromote-to-excom/(?P<user>\d+)/$', views.DePromoteExcom, 
name='depromote'),
url(r'^remove-from-hub/(?P<user>\d+)/$', views.RemoveFromHub, 
name='remove_from_hub'),

url(r'^view-hubs/$', views.HubListView, name='view_all_hubs'),
url(r'^join-hub/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.JoinHub, name='join_hub'),

# url(r'^dashboard/tasks/(?P<task_id>\d+)/like/$', views.Tasklike, 
name='task-like'),
url(r'^level/$', views.StudentLevelListView, name='level'),
url(r'^level/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.StudentLevelDetailView, 
name='level-detail'),
url(r'^level/(?P<pk>\d+)/(?P<todo_id>\d+)/$', views.TaskCreateView, 
name='task-form'),
url(r'^hub/$', views.StudentHubListView, name='hub'),
url(r'^subscribe/member/$',views.MemberPay,name='member'),
url(r'^subscribe/fellow/$', views.FellowPay, name='fellow'),
url(r'^payment-member/success$', views.payment_success_member,  
name="payment_success_member"),
url(r'^payment-member/failure$', views.payment_failure_member, 
name="payment_failure_member"),
url(r'^payment-fellow/success$', views.payment_success_fellow, 
name="payment_success_fellow"),
url(r'^payment-fellow/failure$', views.payment_failure_fellow, 
name="payment_failure_fellow"),
```

]

js:

```
 $(".likebutton").on('click', function (event) {
 event.preventDefault();
 post_id=$(this).attr('value');
  console.log('CLICKED IN LIKE');
    $.ajax({
type:'post',
    url: post_id+'/like/',
    data: {
  csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()

    },

 success: function (data) {
       alert("SUCESSS");
      if (data.success) {
       console.log("SUCCESS")
        $(this).parents('.timeline-footer').html('<p class="pull-left 
  m-r-15">'+data.likecount+ 'Likes </p>'+
                 '<a class="likebutton" style="color: blue"'+
                   'href="dashboard/tasks/'+ post_id +'/like/"'+ 
 'class="m-r-15 text-inverse-lighter"><i'+
                        'class="fa fa-thumbs-up fa-fw fa-lg m-r-3"> 
 </i>'+
                    'Like</a>'+
                '<a href="dashboard/tasks/'+post_id  +'/$/" class="m- 
 r-15 text-inverse-lighter"><i'+
                        'class="fa fa-comments fa-fw fa-lg m-r-3"> 
</i>'+
                    'Comment</a>')

        // here you update the HTML to change the active to innactive
      }else{
      console.log("ERROR");
        alert("ajax call not success.");
      }
},
     crossDomain: false


});
 });



 $(".likebuttons").on('click', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
 post_id=$(this).attr('value');
 console.log('CLICKED IN LIKE');
    $.ajax({
     headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'},
 type:'post',
    url: 'like/',
    data: {
  csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()

    },

 success: function (data) {
       alert("SUCESSS");
      if (data.success) {
       console.log("SUCCESS")
        $(this).parents('.timeline-footer').html('<p class="pull-left 
 m-r-15">'+data.likecount+ 'Likes </p>'+
                 '<a class="likebutton" style="color: blue"'+
                   'href="dashboard/tasks/'+ post_id +'/like/"'+ 
 'class="m-r-15 text-inverse-lighter"><i'+
                        'class="fa fa-thumbs-up fa-fw fa-lg m-r-3"> 
</i>'+
                    'Like</a>'+
                '<a href="dashboard/tasks/'+post_id  +'/$/" class="m- 
 r-15 text-inverse-lighter"><i'+
                        'class="fa fa-comments fa-fw fa-lg m-r-3"> 
</i>'+
                    'Comment</a>')

        // here you update the HTML to change the active to innactive
      }else{
      console.log("ERROR");
        alert("ajax call not success.");
      }
},

    crossDomain: false


 });
});
```

I have included like section from here:

```
 <div class="timeline-footer">

   {% include 'like_comment2.html' %}
    <a href="javascript:;" class="m-r-15 text-inverse-lighter"><i 
 class="fa fa-comments fa-fw fa-lg m-r-3"></i>
        Comment</a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the final working code:

Javascript:

```
$(document).on('click','.likebutton',function(event)  {
event.preventDefault();
post_id=$(this).attr('value');
console.log('CLICKED IN LIKE');
    $.ajax({
    url: post_id+'/like/',
 type:'post',

    data: {
  csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()

 },

  success: function (data) {

       console.log("SUCCESS")
       console.log(data);
        console.log($(this).closest("div").prop("class"));
        $(this).closest('div').html(data)

        // here you update the HTML to change the active to innactive

  }.bind(this),
 error: function(xhr, status, error) {
 var err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
 alert(err.Message);
}

 });
 });
```

My function:

```
 def LikeToggleView(request,pk=None):


    obj = get_object_or_404(Task, pk=pk)

    user = request.user


    if user in obj.like.all():
             obj.like.remove(user)
             note = Notification.objects.create(sender=user, task=obj, 
  notification = user.username + ' Disliked Your Post ' + obj.title)
             note.receiver.add(obj.student)
    else:
             obj.like.add(user)
             note = Notification.objects.create(sender=user, task=obj, 
  notification = user.username + '  Liked Your Post ' + obj.title)
             note.receiver.add(obj.student)


    if request.is_ajax():
     print("AJAX LIKE")
     context={
        'obj':obj,

     }
     html = render_to_string('like_comment.html', context, request=request)
     return HttpResponse(html)
```

like_comment.html:

```
 {% load static %}

 <p class="pull-left m-r-15"> {{ obj.like.count }} Likes </p>

 <form action="{% url 'student:like' pk=obj.id %}" method="POST">
 {% csrf_token %}
 <a href="" type="submit" value="{{ obj.id }}" name="post_id"   
 class="likebutton m-r-15 text-inverse-lighter" {% if request.user in o 
Obj.like.all %} style="background: blue" {% endif %}">Like</a><i class="fa fa- 
thumbs-up fa-fw fa-lg m-r-3"></i>


</form>
 <a href="{% url 'student:task-detail' obj.id %}" class="m-r-15 text-inverse- 
 lighter"><i
                        class="fa fa-comments fa-fw fa-lg m-r-3"></i>
                    Comment</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not actually firing twice, it's firing the Ajax post but then immediately the browser submits the page to the same URL.

You need to prevent the default submit action in your JS:

```
$(".likebutton").on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
   ...
});
```

Comment: even after adding this .This is the logs: CLICKED IN LIKE
14:39:48.725 dashboard.js:36 CLICKED IN LIKE
14:39:48.789 jquery.js:8630 GET http://localhost:8000/student/dashboard/tasks/154/like/ 404 (Not Found)
send @ jquery.js:8630
ajax @ jquery.js:8166
(anonymous) @ VM793 dashboard.js:37
dispatch @ jquery.js:4435
r.handle @ jquery.js:4121
14:39:48.819 jquery.js:8630 GET http://localhost:8000/student/dashboard/tasks/154/like/ 404 (Not Found)
send @ jquery.js:8630
ajax @ jquery.js:8166
(anonymous) @ dashboard.js:37

Comment: i added the document.ready function and now it shows POST http://localhost:8000/student/dashboard/tasks/154/like/ 500 (Internal Server Error)..Still not getting into ajax

Comment: Sorry. I had added a script for the js two times accidently . Now its onlwy firing once  but still its showing error :jquery.js:8630 GET http://localhost:8000/student/dashboard/tasks/154/like/ 404 (Not Found)

Comment: You should show the full app and project urls.py files.

Comment: how would i share it with you?

Comment: Edit the question and post them there.

Comment: figured it out.Thanks!